# changing or adding hours to a datetime in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

im having a problem with datetime in rails. Im reading a json and saving dates in a model. that has a column `t.date:datetime`
The thing is there is 2 dates that i get from this json, and i want only to save it as 1.
I get date for day : `2022-04-16 00:00:00` and also i get a hour date : `01:00:00` is there a way to add that hour date to my day date ? Like getting `2022-04-16 01:00:00` ?

Im new to rails so sorry if im not explaining correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your time to second and then add it to your date

```rb
date = "2022-04-16 00:00:00".to_datetime
time = Time.parse("01:00:00").seconds_since_midnight.seconds

date + time
```

You don't need to do `to_datetime`if your date is already a datetime object

Answer (score 2):

An hour is 1/24th of a day. DateTime happily let's you add that to a date.

```
t1 = DateTime.today
t2 = t1 + 1/24r # a rational number. 1.0/24 is fine too.
```